# How to Access when the table of column <td> tag contains `display:none` in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to access which column are in style display none

I take table columns like this:

```
<% ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query); %>
<% while(rs.next()) { %>
  <tbody>
    <tr>         
      <td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td>
      <td style="display:none;"><%=rs.getString(6)%></td>
      <td style="display:none;" id="name"><%=rs.getString(7)%></td>                 
      <td style="display:none;"><%=rs.getString(8)%></td>                       
    </tr>
<% } %>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function printIt(){ 
   var name=document.getElementById("name").value; 
   alert(name);
}
</script>

<body><input type="submit" value="Get Value" onclick="printIt();"/></body>
```

When i click button it shows alert in `Undefined`  how can i access this

Comment: Where is the element with the id `name`?

Comment: Try `$("td[style*='display:none']"));`

Comment: CSS styles applied to elements (including `display`) does not affect their position in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Element.value` you should use the [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

Code example:

```js
function printIt() { 
  var name = document.getElementById('name').innerHTML; 
  console.log(name);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="WorkAreaNew.jsp?id=1">Dynamic text 1</a></td>
    <td>Dynamic text 2</td>
    <td style="display:none;">Dynamic text 3</td>
    <td style="display:none;" id="name">Dynamic text 4</td>                 
    <td style="display:none;">Dynamic text 5</td>                       
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Get Value" onclick="printIt();"/>
```

Comment: I think he needs all columns with style `display: none`

Comment: Hi,@Yosvel Quintero, I need data from data base value how can i display

Comment: Thanks @HarikrishnanN Updated the answer

Comment: How can i access single value i gave `id` to `<td>` but it is not getting value. i need to assign those values into text box values

Comment: @RobertE I have updated the answer.. Your code is almost done: you only need to use `Element.innerHTML` instead of `Element.value`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need all the `td` which is `style="display:none"`

```js
function printIt() { 
  $("td[style*='display:none']").each(function(){
  
     console.log($(this).text());
  }); 
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td  style="display:none;">Some string here...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td  style="display:none;">Some string here...123</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Get Value" onclick="printIt();"/>
```